# Unexpected value returned from mktime()

Tags: c++, c, time, timestamp, mktime

I prepare the following structure :

```
struct tm tDepartureTime;
tDepartureTime.tm_min = 24;
tDepartureTime.tm_hour = 13;
tDepartureTime.tm_mday = 11;
tDepartureTime.tm_mon = 2 - 1;
tDepartureTime.tm_year = 2017 - 1900;
```

then I use mktime() to get the number of seconds.

```
unsigned long qTime = mktime( &tDepartureTime );
```

but it returns me number **1731157832** which is timestamp equivalent for  09.11.2024. 
Where could be a problem?

Comment: Did you intend the date to be in February 2017?  (The values of `tm_mon` run from 0 for January to 11 for December.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, yes Jonathan, it was intended for February. Anyway thank you for notify me.

Comment: OK. Since you wrote `2017 - 1900` but didn't write `2 - 1` I wasn't sure, but it didn't materially affect your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some fields of your `tm` structure are uninitialized. Specifically, these are `tm_sec`, `tm_mday`, `tm_wday`, `tm_yday` and `tm_isdst`.

Of these, you need to manually set, at the very least, `tm_sec`. If its value randomly ends up being very high, that explains the time far into the future.

You could also initialize the entire struct with zeroes by changing your first line into `struct tm tDepartureTime = {0}`. This is probably the best solution.

Comment: The values of `tm_wday`, `tm_yday` don't matter and are set as a side-effect of calling `mktime()`.  The value was set for `tm_mday`.  As you correctly said, the value in `tm_sec` was not set and the value actually present was probably quite large.